# How to get a PHP loop to run via a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

(This has now been resolved - thanks @ChelseaStats)

I have built a web page in PHP. users log in and upload photos and stories, and the page displays the stories and photos immediately.

The problem is that the photos that the MySQL query and PHP return from the database are being displayed all over the place. I have printed them out in an id’d div but the CSS is having no control over their positioning.

Currently the query is like this:

```
$q1 = "SELECT * from images ORDER BY date ASC";
```

and they are displayed like this...

```
row1 = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q1);

echo '<div id = "pictures">';
while ( $fix1 = mysqli_fetch_array($row1) ) {
  echo '
 <img style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;" height = "80" width = "80" src = "data:image;base64,'.$fix1['image'].'"><br>'.$fix1['image_id'].'
 ';}
  echo '</div id = "pictures">';
```

What I would like to do is store all the 'while loop' programming in a variable, then print that variable out elsewhere on the HTML page away from php script so that when the database query is run, I can use the results to fill/initialize the variable (e.g. $displayPics) which will then be printed out on the html page where I want it to appear.

I realise this may be impossible and I am open to suggestions...

...or I might be willing to run a query with a limit of **20** giving results in descending date order and then assigning ‘loop-free’ PHP code to a variable which I can then print out on the page elsewhere.

Code could look something like this:

```
 row1 = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q1);
 $fix1 = mysqli_fetch_array($row1);

 $displayPics = '
 <img style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;" height = "40" width = "40" src = "data:image;base64,\'.$row1[$fix1[\'image\']].\'"><br>\'.$row1[$fix1[\'image\']].\'
 ';
```

(Above code is a shot at how I imagine it will look). (I think the img src code and html has been filtered out by the forum possibly).

But maybe this code will be repeated **20x** in the variable with row number changing for each subsequent repetition perhaps?

(I basically want better control over the positioning of the pics coming back from the database).

Comment: Can you post your actual PHP output, your desired PHP output, and the PHP that you're using to generate it?  The random snippets are not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

in a foreach you can assign to a variable like this

```
$bob = ''; // set it
foreach($row as $image) {
   // append to it
   $bob .= '<div id=""><img src="" /></div>'.PHP_EOL;
}

print $bob;
```

similar would work for you.

Comment: further to the edit you have a closing `echo '</div id = "pictures">';` you just need `</div>` also check your `img` tag is being closed `/>` correctly.

Comment: thanks very much this works like a charm... except, now all of my image_id's stored in my database (that I want to print under the pics) as 'image_id' (int 10) now come out as '1' instead of their assigned image_id eg 2, 3 or 4. please help me out...               $displaypics .= '<div id=""><img style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;" height = "40" width = "40" src = "data:image;base64,'.$fix1['image'].'"><br>'.$fix1['image_id'].'

Comment: thanks. ive corrected that. i've closed the img properly as you said, but i am able to get other database info without problem, just that image_id is always being returned as '1'. I'm baffled.

Comment: i now know it is because it is printing the same image out every time, im not sure how to make the code print out different images (despite the loop). that is the problem, not image_id request error....!

Answer (score 0):

if you use Bootstrap- you can assign a display class as it is rendered. The following will display each image as follows (4 across on a medium to large viewport, 3 across on a small viewport, and two across on a mobile sized viewport). Also note the use of figcaption to provide the caption on each image.

```
row1 = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q1);

while ( $fix1 = mysqli_fetch_array($row1) ) {
   echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6'>
       <figure>
         <img style = 'border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;' height = '80' width = '80' src = 'data:image;base64,".$fix1['image']."'/>

        <figcaption>".$fix1['image_id']."</figcaption>
      </figure>
 </div>
 ";}
```

Comment: thanks. I'm sure that would work, but I want to call a function, or call a variable someplace else on the page so that I can control where the images appear exactly. I'm not sure this would help me do that, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a function that returns all of the rows into an array of assoc arrays and loop through them when you need them elsewhere in the code and use conditional tests on the rows to have better control over where they go!

```
function getImages(){
       $imgs = array();
       while(($next = mysqli_fetch_assoc(...)){
         array_push($imgs, $next);
       }
       return $imgs; //array of assoc arrays
    }
```

Comment: thanks I'm believe that that would work well, but I just don't understand, if you can i would really appreciate it if you elaborated...

Comment: The idea here is to get all of the images in one function resulting in an array of associative arrays (rows) from the database.  One query is ran and all of the results are returned in one place using the function.  In your code, you could run getImages() and throughout the code you can reference the result and print images where they need to be by simply looking through the array instead of running another query.  You could also write functions that extract certain elements from the array to prevent lots of loops appearing in the code.  I hope this helps. Happy St. Patty's day.